# Autocomplete field with multiple values (removable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[image: Example]

I would like to design my field exactly like this one.

I have everything up and running like [this code snippet](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple):

But I want these little crosses to remove selections :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could make use of [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). [Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/dzyggftn/)
Or perhaps you like [this one](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-jQuery-UI-Plugin-For-Simle-Tokenized-Autocomplete-Autocomplete-Multiselect/) better.
So plenty of plugins available that do what you describe.

```
$('.chosen-select').chosen({}).change( function(obj, result) {
    console.debug("changed: %o", arguments);

    console.log("selected: " + result.selected);
});
```

Completely different question added in comment, how to populate a select in php.
Take the jsfiddle above, and instead of `<option value="United States">United States</option>` you will: `echo "<option value='$value'>$name</option>";` in your foreach loop. Prior to the foreach loop you add the:

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select" multiple style="width:350px;" tabindex="4">
            <option value=""></option>
```

and after your foreach loop you get: `</select>`

Comment: I have a taxonomy as database for this input field.

Right now I am using this code to get the data:

<?php 
$categories = get_terms( 'category',
    array ( 'fields' => 'id=>name')
    );
$help1;
foreach ($categories as $single_object) {
    $help1[] =array ($single_object);
}
$help2;
for($i=0; $i < count($help1); $i++){
    $help2[] = $help1[$i][0];
}

So the question: How do i get this data in the select field? :D